# Can the Illusion wizard's Illusory Reality feature be used to make food or potions?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard, illusion, food-and-drink

Can the School of Illusion wizard’s Illusory Reality feature be used for self-sustainment and healing?

Illusory Reality specifies that “you can choose one inanimate, nonmagical object that is part of the illusion and make that object real.”

Well, at least to me, there is nothing magical or animated about a ham sandwich or a glass of water or a potion of healing.

It seems like many people focus on its uses for damage when they ask these kinds of questions, but what about for healing or nourishment? Is it possible to create an illusion of a piece of cooked meat and make it real, then eat it to save yourself from starvation? What about healing? Can you make a potion and use it to heal yourself in an emergency?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Thanks for specifying 5e, but the [dnd-5e] tag is all we really need, so I've edited out the other mentions of 5e (although feel free to [edit] them back in if you'd prefer); I've also split up the paragraphs (you need to either add two spaces before a new line, or add two new lines, otherwise it ignores the new line entirely). Anyway, I've now voted for this to be reopened.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Not practically.

[Potions are magic items.](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#Consumables) Illusory Reality works only on "one inanimate, nonmagical object that is part of the illusion", so you couldn't turn an illusion of a potion real.

Food is generally not magical, but you can only make it real for one minute. What exactly happens if you've already eaten it is up to your DM, but it is most likely just sitting in your stomach at that point, not digested and absorbed. The point is, you won't ever get to digest it. It's nutritionally void.